# Is there a 2d physics engine that can model fluids and gases?

Tags: 2d, physics

At this point the platform and programming language don't matter I would just like to know if something out there exists for this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This kind of question always need more specification in terms of *what behaviors* you need to model and *how realistic* you insist on it being.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the most useful thing I was able to find - a box2d add-on prototype written in java:
http://www.jbox2d.org/liquid/

A good discussion about the issue:
http://box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=574&hilit=liquid&start=20

Answer (score 1):

This impressed me a lot:

http://www.scuzzstuff.org/oe_cake/
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1W_ZF2CS9RE